# problem finding variable values starting with tab

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, make

I'm trying to write a simple Linux `make` command with bash scripting. here is what I have written so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function make_cmd()
{
  read target colon sources
  for src in $sources; do
    if [ $src -nt $target ]; then
      while read cmd && [[ $(echo "$cmd" | grep "$(printf '\t')"*) ]]; do
        echo "executing $cmd";
        eval ${cmd#$(printf '\t')};
      done
      break;
    fi
  done
}
```

this is the format of input:

```
target.file : source.file
[tab]command
```

for example:

```
target.txt : source.txt
    ls
    cd
```

the script works well but it cannot find commands starting with tab. it always execute them. for example, the commands in this input is still executed.

```
target.txt : source.txt
ls
cd
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: The problem is the use of `read`, which splits on whitespace i.e. including tabs. Perhaps do `IFS=' '` at the beginning to let only a space separate words.

Comment: See also: [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builtin `read` command splits words using the value of `IFS`, which by default contains a space, a tab and a newline. Hence when using `read` to get the input, the tab is removed.

Begin the function with:

```
IFS_SAVE="$IFS"
IFS=' '
```

Now only spaces will separate words. At the end of the function restore IFS to its original value:

```
IFS="$IFS_SAVE"
```

Note that you can use a literal tab if escaped by a backslash. Furthermore I would not use `grep` to match the tab, use builtins where possible as that's faster. My version of the function would be:

```
function make_cmd()
{
  SAVE_IFS="$IFS"
  IFS=' '
  read target colon sources
  for src in $sources; do
    if [ $src -nt $target ]; then
      while read cmd; do
        case "$cmd" in
          $'\t'*)  echo "executing $cmd"
                eval ${cmd# }
                ;;
          *)    ;;
        esac
      done
      break;
    fi
  done
  IFS="$SAVE_IFS"
}
```

The `$'\t'` substitutes a literal tab (thanks to Kusalananda for the tip).

Insert a literal tab after the `#` in the variable substitution. Using the `printf` might be more readable though.

Comment: I added the lines you said to my code, still doesn't work. your code does not execute the cmd no matter how it is entered.

Comment: If you run `cat -t filename` on your script, does it show the tabs in the code as `^I`? E.g. `^I\^I*)^Iecho "executing $cmd"`. If not, your editor isn't inserting the tabs as-is.

Comment: yes your right. it doesn't insert tabs. I will fix this and test everything again

Comment: @FatemehKarimi You may also be able to use `$'\t'*)` in the `case` statement.

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks my dear friend. I replaced it with $'\t'*) and it solved my problem.

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect Kusalananda's tip.